# Show menu without call setSupportActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

in my activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar );
```

as result in all fragments with parent this activity, success call automatically method  `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

in my fragment:

```
private MenuItem checkStateMenuItem;
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cart_pay_menu_actionbar, menu);
        checkStateMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

as result , when show fragment, in toolbar success show menu.
Nice.

The question is:

Is it possible to show menu in toolbar when NOT call method `setSupportActionBar()` ? Or maybe has some another options to call automatically `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Any concern why you don't want to call `setSupportActionBar()`?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes, I can't use AppCompatActivity. I has not source code of this part of our project. I can use only FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

Just use the toolbar APIs directly, the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `setSupportActionBar` methods are just there to make the transition between ActionBar and Toolbar easier.

```
 toolbar.post {
        inflateMenu()
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_24)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().onBackPressed()
        }
    }

private fun inflateMenu() {
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.product_menu)
    val menu = toolbar.menu
}
```